# Routing a segment of IP address from one vpn to another

Tags: routes

My base os is ubuntu and on it i have two vpns. For work related i need to connect to two vpns. One is pulse secure and the other is forticlient. For some reason i need to connect to 192.168.0.0 subnet in forticlient vpn. But whenever i connect to pulse secure my 192.168.0.0 subnet towards forticlient is not working. Hence everytime i need to disconnect and connect pulse.

1. Can any one help me on how to use route command or IPTables or anyother option to help route 192.168.0.0 subnet to one vpn while rest on another vpn.
   Note: I have only wireless connections no lan
2. How can i use a script to connect and disconnect pulse secure vpn. Also it has mfa enabled.
3. How to permanently add or remove routes in ubuntu via terminal

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer by using the following steps. Thought if this could help someone, so answering my own question.

Step 1:

Connect the first VPN

Step 2:

Connect the second VPN

Step 3:

When you use `route -n` command, you can see two virtual interface being created viz. `tun0` and `tun1`.

Step 4:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev tun0
```

Step 5:

If you are in Ubuntu just like me then:

```
sudo netplan apply
```